# Space between my recent posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for ages to figure out how to add some space between my recent posts on a wordpress site.

Really have no idea. Anybody that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 style statements that pretty directly affect these. One has bottom margin but is being overridden by another with `margin: 0;`. Change this to `margin: 0 0 20px 0;`.

```
.primary_content_wrap ul li {
    background: url(images/marker.gif) no-repeat 1px 11px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 17px;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #005d9e;
}

.recent-posts li {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the help. If I edit the stylesheet and add the margin it works, but this margin will appear on other places on the website. Is there a way to add the margin only between those posts? Thanks

Comment: Make your own class just for those posts

Comment: Yes, simple enough as @JustinJasmann suggests, create a new class for these, or figure out how to be more specific with your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

each of your posts is a li with an "entry" class :

```
<li class="entry">...</li>
```

it seems there's nothing in any CSS for that entry class. What I would do is define it in the CSS with a margin-bottom set to, let's say 10px.